# How to replace multiple regex matches in text block

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying convert multiple matches in a paragraph into links while preserving the surrounding text in my final output. The pattern I am matching is reminiscent of the hyperlink syntax for Markdown, as a way of allowing non-technical users to define what text they'd like linked in the input (a Google Sheet I am accessing via the Sheets API/Python). The first group I am capturing is the linked text and the second is the value for a key in the query string.

I've been able to successfully match a single instance of this pattern, but my replacement string replaces my entire paragraph in the output.

```
text = "2018 was a big year for my sourdough starter and me. Mostly 
we worked on developing this [tangy bread](19928) and these [chewy 
rolls] (9843). But we were also just content keeping each other 
company and inspired to bake."

def link_inline(text):
    # expand a proper link around recipe id
    ref = re.search(r"(\[.*?\]\(\d+\))", text, re.MULTILINE).group(1)
    if (len(ref) > 0):
        link = re.sub("\[(.*?)\]\((\d+)\)", r"<a href='https://www.foo.com/recipes?rid=\2'>\1</a>", ref)
        return text
    else:
        return "replacement failed"
```

The goal is to have this output keep the paragraph intact, and simply replace the `\[(.*?)\]\((\d+)\)` pattern matches with the following string, including backreferences for the groups: `<a href="https://www.foo.com?bar=\2">\1</a>`

So it will need to loop through the text to replace all matches, (presumably with `re.finditer`?) and also maintain the original text outside of the pattern match. But I am unsure how to define the loop properly and perform this replacement without overwriting the whole paragraph with just my replacement string.

Comment: Strings can not be changed. There variables can only be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

I used `re.compile`, and instead of putting parentheses around the entire group, I put one pair around the `.*?` and another pair around the `\d+`, since those two parts represent the text we want to extract and put into our URLs.

```
import re

def link_inline(text):
    # expand a proper link around recipe id
    ref = re.compile("\[(.*?)\]\((\d+)\)")
    replacer = r'<a href="https://www.foo.com/recipes?rid=\2">\1</a>'
    return ref.sub(replacer, text)


text = """
2018 was a big year for my sourdough starter and me. Mostly we worked on
 developing this [tangy bread](19928) and
 these [chewy rolls](9843). But we were also just
 content keeping each other company and inspired to bake.
"""

print(link_inline(text))
```

Output:

```
2018 was a big year for my sourdough starter and me. Mostly we worked on
 developing this <a href="https://www.foo.com/recipes?rid=19928">tangy bread</a> and
 these <a href="https://www.foo.com/recipes?rid=9843">chewy rolls</a>. But we were also just
 content keeping each other company and inspired to bake.
```

As a sanity check, I tried throwing in some extra strings with parentheses and brackets that weren't links, like `(this) here` and `[this] here` within the string `text`.  Things still ran OK.

Comment: I was able also get it working using `re.findall` to generate an array of the matches, then added a for loop with my same `re.sub` function from the original post. It seems your approach with `re.compile` is far simpler however. Why doesn't that require a loop?